# Backbone edit model

Tags: templates, backbone.js, model, field, rounding

I tried to find a simple solution for my problem, but I couldn't.
So I have model like this:

```
App.Models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "ItemID",
    defaults:
            {
                ItemID: 1,
                TypeID: 1,
                Name: "",
                Price: 1.00,
                Image: "",
            },
    urlRoot: 'api/items'
});
```

in my chtml file I have this:

```
<div class='wrapper'>  
    <a href="#" data-id ="<%= ItemID %>"><img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= Image %>" class="image"/></a>
    <div class ="price">
        <%= Price %>
    </div>
    <div class='description'>  
        <p class='description_content'><%= Name %></p>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

I just want to edit each "Price" field to have two decimal places. Something like Math.round... but I don't now how to implement this script with the Backbone model. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the view that binds your model to your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If server returns a price that doesn't have two decimals you can fix it in the `parse` method. Or you can just format an output in your template:

```
<%= Price.toFixed(2) %>
```

Comment: :-) I tried it (the same way) and I did something wrong obviously. It works! Thank you. What if I need to use Math.round?

Comment: Like this `<%= Math.round(Price).toFixed(2) %>`?